# T-SQL getting all unique groups with their usage count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, grouping

How do I find the unique groups that are present in my table, and display how often that type of group is used?

For example (SQL Server 2008R2)

[image: Example Data]

So, I would like to find out how many times the combination of

```
PMI 100 
RT 100
VT 100
```

is present in my table and for how many itemid's it is used;

These three form a group because together they are assigned to a single itemid. The same combination is assigned to id 2527 and 2529, so therefore this group is used at least twice. (usagecount = 2)

(and I want to know that for all types of groups that are appearing)

- The entire dataset is quite large, about 5.000.000 records, so I'd like to avoid using a cursor.
- The number of code/pct combinations per itemid varies between 1 and 6.
- The values in the "code" field are not known up front, there are more than a dozen values on average

I tried using pivot, but I got stuck eventually and I also tried various combinations of GROUP-BY and counts.

Any bright ideas?

Example output:

```
code pct groupid usagecount
PMI  100 1       234
RT   100 1       234
VT   100 1       234
CD   5   2       567
PMI  100 2       567
VT   100 2       567
PMI  100 3       123
PT   100 3       123
VT   100 3       123
RT   100 4       39
VT   100 4       39
etc
```

Comment: I may not be comprehending correctly here, but do you just need a flat list of code, pct, no of appearances? If so, `SELECT code, pct, count(*) as VOL FROM [TABLENAME] GROUP BY code, pct` should work for you? If not, could you put your desired ouput format please?

Comment: Example output added.

Comment: Could you check my example and tell me if I got your question right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using a simple group:

```
SELECT
    code
    , pct
    , COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY 
    code
    , pct
```

Not too sure if that's more like what you're looking for:

```
select
    uniqueGrp
    , count(*)
from (
    select distinct
        itemid
    from myTable
) as I
cross apply (
    select 
         cast(code as varchar(max)) + cast(pct as varchar(max)) + '_'
    from myTable
    where myTable.itemid = I.itemid
    order by code, pct
    for xml path('')
) as x(uniqueGrp)
group by uniqueGrp
```

Comment: Nope, that is the count for just one code/pct combination. I need the count for the whole group of (in my highlighted example) 3 records of  code/pct combinations.
I need to know how often that group of 3 records is used.

Comment: I see where you are going, but your sample results in a single record.

Comment: Ok, I definitively don't get what your grouping logic is.

Comment: see itemid 2527 and 2529 in the example data, they have the same group assigned.

Comment: the xml solution seems weird to me, but it works like perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Either of these should return each combination of code and percentage with a group id for the code and the total number of instances of the code against it.  You can use them for also adding the number of instances of the specific code/pct combo too for determining % contribution etc

```
select
distinct
t.code, t.pct, v.groupcol, v.vol
from
[tablename] t
inner join (select code, rank() over(order by count(*)) as groupcol,
  count(*) as vol from [tablename] s
  group by code) v on v.code=t.code
```

or

```
select
t.code, t.pct, v.groupcol, v.vol
from
(select code, pct from [tablename] group by code, pct)  t
inner join (select code, rank() over(order by count(*))  as groupcol,
  count(*) as vol from [tablename] s
  group by code) v on v.code=t.code
```

Comment: the rank() assigns a group-id for a single code-pct combination, i need those combinations grouped by their combined usage on items

Comment: good spot - had partitioned by code instead of ordering by count(*) - amended now

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by Code, and Pct should be enough I think. See the following :

```
select code,pct,count(p.*)
from [table] as p
group by code,pct
```